# Password reset email not sending with the addition of a custom template

Tags: django, email, password-recovery

Trying to get my custom template to display with my password reset email, but it's not working. The email sends, but the custom email template does not render.

```
 path('accounts/password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='password_reset.html',
        html_email_template_name='password_reset_email_template.html',
        subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt'
       ), name='password_reset'),
```

password_reset_email_template.html:

```
<html>
<tr>
 <td style="color:#333333; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; padding-bottom:18px;text-align:left;">
   {% load i18n %}
     {% autoescape off %}  You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for  account. {% endautoescape %}
 <p>Follow the link below to reset:</p>
<a  href="https://domain{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}"> Reset Password </a>
</td>
</html>
```

Comment: you can follow this tutorial if you want to override the template https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-password-reset/

Comment: @Nalin, so I followed that tutorial and the words and link renders, but I cannot get the logo and design of my email to render. So everything after the {% autoescape off %} seems to render, but not the html before or after those tags.

Comment: AFAIK images should be served by external server, you cannot serve images from your local system and CSS should be inline/internal.